# get the value from a text input after it is updated in react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, dom

I'm learning React and I need help understanding how to create functions for values that are updated asynchronously in the DOM.  For instance, I have a text input within a component called header that looks like this:

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return (
                <div className="Header">
                <div><input onKeyDown={this.props.onEnter} id="filter-results" className="full" type="text" placeholder="search kks"></input></div>
                <div><button className="full">SEARCH</button></div>
                </div>
        );
    }

}
```

, which is used to filter search results.  The onEnter function tries to use the value updated in the input:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            categories: [],
            searchResults: [],

        };
        this.filterSearch = this.filterSearch.bind(this);
    }
    filterSearch(){
        var el = document.getElementById('filter-results').value
        console.log(el)
        var result = this.state.categories.filter(row => {
            var rx = new RegExp(el)
            return rx.test(row['id'])
        });
        console.log(result)
    }
    render(){
        return (
                <div className="App">
                <Header onEnter={this.filterSearch}/>
                </div>

        );
    }
}
```

When I type something into the input, the element's value is logged to the console.  The problem is, what is logged is always one character less than what I expect to see.  If I type 'a', I get '', 'ab' => 'a', etc.  I can understand conceptually that when the function is triggered and the logging occurs the value hasn't yet been updated, but I don't know how to wait for the value to be updated and then work with it.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onChange instead.

```
//change handler
handler(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
}
//input's onChange event
onChange={ this.handler.bind(this) }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You should not be using native javascript to get value by id. This is not react way of doing.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Header from "./Header";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categories: [],
      searchResults: []
    };
    this.filterSearch = this.filterSearch.bind(this);
  }
  filterSearch(value) {
    console.log(value);
    var result = this.state.categories.filter(row => {
      var rx = new RegExp(value);
      return rx.test(row["id"]);
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header onEnter={this.filterSearch} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

// Header.js

```
import React from "react";

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value
    });
    this.props.onEnter(target.value);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Header">
        <div>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            name="filter-results"
            className="full"
            type="text"
            placeholder="search kks"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button className="full">SEARCH</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```